# Javascript arrays and updating <ul><li></li></ul> elements with a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm struggling with this one a little. I'm a junior python developer by trade and I have been asked to build a website. Naturally I said yes and chose Django. Regardless, I'm having a little issue building a calendar widget. I'm using AJAX to pass the request back to the view, and update certain elements based on whether the user is requesting the previous/next month of days.

```
  function getPreviousMonth( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "{% url 'events' %}",
        data: { 'month': previousMonth, 'year': previousYear }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        nextMonth = response.next_month;
        nextYear  = response.next_year;
        previousMonth = response.previous_month;
        previousYear  = response.previous_year;

        currentMonth = response.current_month;
        currentYear  = response.current_year;

        $('#currentMonth').text(currentMonth);
        $('#currentYear').text(currentYear);
    });
  };
```

This all seems to be working well. In the response object I have an array of lists (I think, certainly correct me if I am wrong). On the template side I am using Django to setup the calendar from an array of days arrays:

```
  {% for week in weeks %}
  <ul class="days">
    {% for day in week %}
      {% if day == 0 %}
        <li></li>
      {% else %}
        <li>{{ day }}</li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endfor %}
```

All looks nice (and importantly, functions spot on):

[image]

What I now want to do, is perform the same logic for the unoredered list (class="days") on the template after response is met. I have the days as the following (the "weeks" array, 0 if the day is contained in the month, overwise it has the day of the month as an integer, hopefully this makes sense):

[image]

Above is after clicking on the next month, so this corresponds to the days in February. So for each [] list in the array of lists - I want to go in, and update all li's within a ul - hopefully that makes sense. A loop within a loop essentially.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I’m not confident with how to loop over such an array structure to replace text inside existing list of unordered lists...

Comment: Empty the `<ul>` and add new `<li>` instead. Not sure why you want to re-invent the wheel here either when there are lots of scripts around for calendars/datepickers

Comment: Are there any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to recreate what you've made with the django template in javascript.

As you're using jQuery this should work:

```
// Make this selector more specific if needed
$("ul.days").each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('li').each(function (j) {
        if (weeks[i][j]) {
            $(this).html(weeks[i][j]);
        } else {
            $(this).html('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is looking promising I think - what I have done is added an id to each ul of id="{{ forloop.counter0 }}" which indicates 0,1,2,3,4 for each loop iteration (this is a Django "variable"). How would I target each selector from this?

Comment: Scrap that - absolutely worked first time!! Thank you Jens.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Cool! Don't forget to accept once you're able to ;)

Comment: To explain further: I used the reverse approach of yours. I loop through the html elements and try to find the new value in your array. You could also loop through your array (with `for` or `.forEach`) and try to find each element, with either your id idea or just getting nth-element.

Comment: Thanks Jens - I just need to figure out a way of adding events with a css class within this loop, but all looks amazing!

Comment: Well in that case it would be quite easy, as once you're inside the true condition of the if statement you know the day. If you pass an array in which the key is the day of month and the value is your event/array of events, you can access that event with `events[weeks[i][j]]` and apply your css with `$(this).addClass('whatever')`. Don't forget to clear all classes though once you switch

Comment: I'm thinking I might add in a span class for this inside the li if needed. I'd likely need to just return a list of numbers for a given month then if `weeks[i][j]` in this list of numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163546/discussion-between-michael-roberts-and-jensv).

Comment: Hi again Jens - can I pick something up with in chat?